# Are there any alternatives to EFS for transparently encrypting the contents of a folder in Windows?

Tags: encryption, windows

EFS is not an option for me because I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium.

I am looking for folder encryption, not drive encryption.

Comment: your title says to encrypt a folder, but the body says the entire drive - which are you looking for?

Comment: TrueCrypt? You can use it under either OS, but it may not be as transparent as you like.

Comment: Looking for something that works like EFS but is compatible with the Home editions of Windows.

Comment: Related question: SuperUser.com, 2015-09-16, [*How to Encrypt Home Directory on Windows 10 Home?*](http://superuser.com/questions/973905/how-to-encrypt-home-directory-on-windows-10-home)

Comment: @JohnDeters TrueCrypt is no longer developed/secure, but VeraCrypt could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible in your context, but I'd say that you want to use Container-based encryption.
That way you create a container file (using VeraCrypt/TrueCrypt/BestCrypt/...) which you mount as a new drive afterwards. The mounted drive can be used transparently for data accesses.
If you can't move the folder you want to encrypt, than you can still use container-based encryption, but add a junction point pointing to your encrypted (virtual) drive.